# PDO individually session for users

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not sure if i'm approaching this right, I'm attempting to store my registeration in an public class, (if that even make sense), anyways, here is my code and it's giving me an 
`unexpected T_PUBLIC error`.

Am i suppose to put my action="" and link it with my class/register.php ?

**register.php**

```
<?php session_start();?>

<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<hr><br />

<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="class/register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

**class/register.php**

```
<?php
  public function register($username, $password){

    require 'core/connect.php';

    $query = $dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
    $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $query->bindParam('password', $_POST['password']);

    if($query->execute()){
      header('Location: Header.php');
    } else {
      echo 'There has been an error.';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Am i suppose to put my action="" and link it with my class/register.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using any **`class`** ( Not able to find any `include` or `require` after the `<?php` tag ), then just remove the **`public`** keyword from your function definition.

Just

`function register($username, $password){` will do

instead of

`public function register($username, $password){`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<?php
    function register($username, $password){

        require 'core/connect.php';

        $query = $dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($query->execute()){
            header('Location: Header.php');
        } else {
            echo 'There has been an error.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: $dbConnect() is in my core/connect.php, by the way, in my register.php am i suppose to link the action="" to my class/regiser.php ?